# Is it possible to use vagrant + aws provider + docker provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, vagrant

I have been starting to mess around with vagrant and AWS. However I would like to now have containers created when I vagrant up and would like to setup my project as a docker project which uses this AWS server as the host.

I managed to get this to work when using virtual-box and specifying `docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"` however when i do the same with having AWS as the host it doesnt seem to work as it seems docker is still attempting to be created locally instead of on the host.

This is how i have my project setup to test. I have the main folder vagrant_docker_aws, inside i have a folder called host which contains my 'host' vagrantfile and then in the root of vagrant_docker_aws i have a vagrantfile with the containers specified. This setup worked locally.

Here is what my host/Vagrantfile looks like. I am on windows using cygwin and rsync.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = ""
    aws.secret_access_key = ""
    aws.instance_type = "t2.micro"
    aws.keypair_name = "dev"
    aws.region = ""
    aws.security_groups = [""]
    aws.associate_public_ip = true
    aws.availability_zone = ""
    aws.subnet_id =""

    aws.ami = "ami-b95d04da"
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = ""
  end

  config.vm.provision "docker"
end
```

This is what the the vagrant file in the root of vagrant_docker_aws looks like.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"
  end

  config.vm.define "nginx-01" do |nginx|
    # can include settings for container such as disabling shared folders using nginx
    nginx.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
      docker.image = "nginx"
      docker.ports = ['80:80', '443:443']
      docker.name = 'nginx-container'
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "postgres-01" do |postgres|
    # can include settings for container such as disabling shared folders using postgres
    postgres.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
      docker.image = "postgres"
      docker.ports = ['5432:5432']
      docker.name = 'postgres-container'
    end
  end
end
```

Basically this is an example of what happens when i run vagrant up from inside vagrant_aws_docker.

```
D:\Projects\vagrant_docker_aws>vagrant up --no-parallel
Bringing machine 'nginx-01' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'postgres-01' up with 'docker' provider...
==> nginx-01: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    nginx-01: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    nginx-01: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    nginx-01:
```

I'm not a 100% sure if this is even possible/a good idea(if not why?), but I would appreciate if anyone has any ideas.

**Note:** I know i shouldnt be sticking my AWS credentials into the file but rather using ENV variables but i would just like to get this working for now.

Comment: Well it looks like when using this setup i need to start the host up separately from the docker vagrantfile. Anyone know why i cant just vagrant up in the dir containing the vagrantfile docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile". Which will then spin up the host and then the the containers?

Comment: Hi @Deep I'm facing a similar problem - don't suppose you have any updates on this?

Comment: Or rather I'm trying to get the same set up working (using an AWS EC2 instance as a host for docker containers) - I appear to have even less joy than you, an equivalent vagrantfile set up yields the output that required AWS parameters are missing when attempting to vagrant up in the vagrant_docker_aws directory

Comment: Hey unfortunately not but I havent tried to tackle the issue since opening this. I did try a couple of things such as defining a named machine for the host (instead of using default) however I ran into a similar issue (try and mess around with the _machine and _vagrantfile settings https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/configuration.html). I am going to try and figure this out pretty soon however and i'll add a solution here if i manage to get it right.